# PHP> Referencing array [0]

Tags: php

How do I reference [0]?

```
object(GetClassSchedulesResult)#8 (6) { 
["ClassSchedules"]=> object(stdClass)#9 (1) { 
["ClassSchedule"]=> array(20) { 
[0]=> object(ClassSchedule)#10 (21) { 
["Classes"]=> string(18) "Rails"
```

This works:

```
$classes = $service->GetClassSchedules($parameters)->
             GetClassSchedulesResult->ClassSchedules->ClassSchedule;
```

I'm trying to get to "Classes". I'm having trouble referencing the [0]:
This does not work:

```
$classes = $service->GetClassSchedules($parameters)->
             GetClassSchedulesResult->ClassSchedules->ClassSchedule->0->Classes;
```

**UPDATE**: Once I reference it correctly, the output always includes something like:

`string(18) "the data i want here" ?>`

Any easy way to get the data without `string(18)` and `?>`?

Comment: How about `...ClassSchedule[0]->Classes`? Read more about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$classes = $service->GetClassSchedules($parameters)->
   GetClassSchedulesResult->ClassSchedules->ClassSchedule[0]->Classes;
```

Comment: @Bruno: Regarding your update, that's the output you normally get using `var_dump`. In your example `Classes` has the value `NULL`, so without more information, we cannot really help you.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok I changed `Classes` from `NULL` to `Rails`

Comment: @Bruno: Ok, but still, there is no problem. `string(18) "Rails"` is the **output** of `var_dump`. The value of `Classes` will still be `Rails`. Did you actually try to work with your data?

Comment: @FelixKling I can work with it just thought there could be a function like var_dump that would give me `Rails` and leave out the rest.

Comment: @Bruno: If you do what ametren is doing in his answer, `$classes` should only contain `Rails`. That's the whole point of my comments. Maybe this helps to clarify my point: http://codepad.org/kfnEsr3u